# Oracle Condition inside IN CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I am writing oracle query to support select all for in clause my query goes something like this

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE 
country_id in( IF('test' = 'test',(1,2,3),true) )
```

If condition ('test' = 'test') is true then it should fire query like

```
SELECT * FROM country WHERE  country_id in(1,2,3)
```

Else it should fire query

```
 SELECT * FROM country WHERE  country_id in(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you need you will have to split it into 2 conditions:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM country
  WHERE(('test'='test')AND(country_id IN (1,2,3)))
     OR(('test'<>'test')AND(country_id<>0))
```

Comment: yes something like this.. but oracle gives error as   `"TRUE": invalid identifier` , Because Orcale doesn't support Boolean type

Comment: For ORACLE everything that is 0 is false and <>0 is true. So the condition should be country_id<>0.